# Need help to select radio button in Chrome using Excel VBA Selenium Basic

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to select a radio button in Chrome (v 75.0.3770.100) using Selenium Basic ChromeDriver (v 75.0.3770.140) in Excel (2013) VBE. Here's the HTML:

```
<tr id="eG9Pg10" class="yw-selector-listitem z-listitem z-listitem-selected">
<td id="eG9Ph10" class="yw-selector-listcell z-listcell">
<div id="eG9Ph10-cave" class="z-listcell-content">
<span id="eG9Pg10-cm" class="z-listitem-checkable z-listitem-radio">
<i class="z-listitem-icon z-icon-radio"></i></span>&nbsp;Store Front Access Backoffice Role</div></td><td id="eG9Pi10" class="yw-selector-listcell z-listcell"> <div id="eG9Pi10-cave" class="z-listcell-content">&nbsp;</div>
```

The ids keep changing each time the page is loaded.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class='z-focus-a']").Click
obj.FindElementByCss("button.z-focus-a[type='button']").Click
```

This is how the Macro starts off...

```
Dim obj As New ChromeDriver
obj.Start "chrome", "   "
obj.Get "https://sh.com/backoffice"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the radio button you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[@class='yw-selector-listcell z-listcell']/div[@class='z-listcell-content' and contains(@id, '-cave')][contains(., 'Store Front Access Backoffice Role')]/span[@class='z-listitem-checkable z-listitem-radio' and contains(@id, '-cm')]").Click
  ```

**Note**: As it is a dynamic element you need to induce a waiter for the *element to be clickable*

Comment: Hi DebanjanB, the code works! Thank you kindly. It selects the first radio button in a list of 5. But how do I need select the 5th one in the list. Each of the elements seem to have the same HTML (except for the dynamic ID) as shown above in this question. The text, however is different. It says "Store Front Access Backoffice Role". Is there any way to index these radio buttons using the cssSelector or xpath?

Comment: @DWP Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status